# Python3 is creating 2 threads for the same job

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, class

I am trying to understand what is happening with my Python code. I have this code:

```
@server.route('/add_device/',methods=['POST'])
def add_device():
    data = request.get_json()
    ip_address = data["IP"]
    interface = data["Interface"]
    thread = Worker(ip_address,interface)
    dev.update_workers(thread,ip_address)
    dev.get_workers()[ip_address].start()
    dev.get_workers()[ip_address].join()
    return 200
```

This is dev, where I keep my dictionary:

```
class devices:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.workers = {}
        
    def update_workers(self,threa,ip_address):
        self.workers[ip_address]=threa
    
    def get_workers(self):
        return self.workers
    
    def remove_devices(self,ip_address):
        del self.workers[ip_address]
    
    def get_connected_devices(self)->list:
        return list(self.workers.keys())
    

dev = devices()
```

This should create a new thread and let it run. Put the thread in a dictionary where I can get it quickly. It is nothing special.

And I have the Worker class:

```
import threading
import time
import requests

class Worker (threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, ip_address, interface):
        super().__init__()
        self.ip_address = ip_address
        self.interface = interface
        self.is_running = True

    def setExit(self):
        self.is_running=False
        print(self.is_running)

    def run(self):
        while self.is_running:
            
            try:
                print(self.is_running)
                print(threading.get_ident())
                response =requests.get(f'https://{self.ip_address}:5001/node_util/all/{self.interface}',verify=False)
                a=response.json()
                # print(a)
                time.sleep(10)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'The error is: {e}')
```

The problem is I am trying to stop the thread, and it is working for 1, but I need to figure out why, by default, it is creating two threads for this class. I am sure it is obvious, but I can not see it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @shaikmoeed I just added dev, it is a class where I keep my dictinary

Comment: Are you seeing similar behavior even if you just run `add_device()` or is it only when your project runs altogether?

Comment: @shaikmoeed 'add_device()' is a function than must be called via an http 
endpoint so I never tried to call it alone

Comment: @shaikmoeed and yes the Debug is False

Comment: You can test `thread=Worker(ip_address,interface);thread.start();thread.join()`, Worker class alone to see, if is it the issue with this class or other parts of your post request.

Comment: @shaikmoeed yes 1 moment

Comment: @shaikmoeed Nope, the same thing

Comment: What is the point of `start()`ing a thread on one line if you're going to `join()` it on the very next line? Why not simply call `dev.get_workers()[ip_address].run()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the client side, because I was testing that part I did not know and the client had the debug on.

Answer (score 0):

This code is designed to have the worker exit when `setExit` is called, or the  `is_running` attribute in a Worker thread instance is set to false.

But your code simply does not do that: it starts the worker thread, with a call to `.start()`, and immediately pauses the execution in the parent thread by calling `worker.join()`: ".join()" will pause the thread were it is called until the target thread is finished. But it won't be finished ever, since it is waiting for some code, outside of that thread, to reset `is_running`.

As I can see here, the wrong part is trying to call the `.join()`  part - just remove that call, and add it to a view where you stop the thread. You have not post it, but I suppose you have a view to call `worker.setExit()` - that is where you may want to add a `.join()` call.

As for why it is running twice: that should only happen if you retry the http post call.